How could I profile a sass-loader compilation?
I'm using embedded-sass in an Angular custom webpack monorepo. One of my libraries with sass takes a significant amount of time just in sass-loader during the build and I'd like to figure out what I could do to have the most impact. I'm already using @use instead of @import. Are there any tools to profile sass? I can switch to the js based dart-sass during profile. I'm guessing the worst case would be to profile the js code itself, but that sounds daunting to say the least
